# Moving v-if logic to model

Tags: vuejs2

Beginner alert....I am trying to understand how to move some of my logic from my view/HTML into the Vue instance. Lets say I have the following code in my HTML. How would I move that into my computed property?

> Sample HTML:

```
<section v-if="(!selectedOffice.inJira) && (selectedProducts === 'Movies')">
```

> Sample Vue instance:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        selectedOffice: '',
        selectedProducts: []
    }
    computed: {
        function() {
        }
    }
});
```

Since I make heavy use of the `v-if` directive in my applications, I'm interested in seeing how moving that to the computed property would be beneficial. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You simply return the evaluated expression in your computed property, i.e.:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        selectedOffice: '',
        selectedProducts: []
    }
    computed: {
        isSelected: function() {
            return !this.selectedOffice.inJira && this.selectedProducts === 'Movies';
        }
    }
});
```

And in your template, you can use this:

```
<section v-if="isSelected">
```

However, there is potentially several issues with your logic, because:

1. `this.selectedOffice` is a string and not an object, so attempting to access `.inJira` might be an issue. You should use declare `selectedOffice` as an empty object instead.
2. `this.selectedProducts` is an array, but you are attempting to evaluate it as a string in your computed property

Comment: Yep Terry is right: 
 selectedOffice: {},
 selectedProducts: ''